# Andriod: How to delete the old quiz and and add new ones?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I'm doing an android quiz and I'm using SQLite to have a local database. Even if I have changed the questions to be displayed, same old questions keep getting displayed.

```
private void addQuestions()
{
    Question q1=new Question("What food makes up nearly all (around 99%)" +
            " of a Giant Panda’s diet?","Bamboo", "Bananas", "Grass", "A");
    this.addQuestion(q1);
}

// Adding new question
public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
    //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
    values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
    values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
    values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
    values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
    // Inserting Row
    dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
}
```

Comment: post the code of how are you deleting the old ones?

Comment: you are just inserting. you should delete old ones or update them

Comment: @Amir ..No I just highlighted and deleted some questions and added new ones.. so when I view them I should see the new ones right?

Comment: @Elenasys No I just highlighted and deleted some questions and added new ones.. so when I view them I should see the new ones right?

Answer (score 0):

Update the Sqlite version to plus 1.

> private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

to

> private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

This will make you application create new db and just insert your new data